# ValueError: The Photo could not be changed because the data didn't validate

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms

I got an issue here, so whenever the users click on the button, the url can show that it manage to get the ID from the link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/packing/15 but it show me this error when it is redirected to the link: ValueError: The Photo could not be changed because the data didn't validate.
How do I fix this error?

This is how after redirect it should looks like, but it just give me an error.
[image]

views.py

```
 @login_required()
def packing(request, id):
    photo = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":

        form = packingForm(request.POST, instance=photo)
        pickingform = pickingForm(request.POST, instance=photo)
        if form.is_valid():

            if form != photo.packing:
                photo.status = 'Packing'
                photo.Datetime = datetime.now()
                form.save()

            return redirect('gallery')

        elif pickingform.is_valid():

            if pickingform != photo.packing:
                photo.status = 'Picking'
                photo.Datetime = datetime.now()
                form.save()

            return redirect('gallery')

    else:
        form = packingForm(instance=photo)
        pickingform = pickingForm(instance=photo)
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "pickingform": pickingform,
        "photo": photo

    }
    return render(request, 'packing.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
    class packingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),)

    packing = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)


    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("packing", )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(packingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['packing'].required = True


class pickingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    PICKING = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    picking = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=PICKING)

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ("picking",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(pickingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['picking'].required = False
```

packing.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>SCS Add Packing or Picking </title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Moment.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-VBLiveTKyUZMEzJd6z2mhfxIqz3ZATCuVMawPZGzIfA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" integrity="sha256-XPTBwC3SBoWHSmKasAk01c08M6sIA5gF5+sRxqak2Qs=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.1.2/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js" integrity="sha256-z0oKYg6xiLq3yJGsp/LsY9XykbweQlHl42jHv2XTBz4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
{% if messages %}
{% for message in messages %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<body class="m-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Add Packing or Picking</h3>

                <a href="{% url 'gallery' %}" class="btn btn-dark my-3">Go Back</a>
                <div class="card" style="width: 400px">


                     <form  method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                        <div class="form-group m-3">

                            <br>
                            <label>Has the item been packed?</label>
                            {{ form.as_p}}



                        </div>

                         <div class="form-group m-3">

                            <br>
                            <label>Has the item been pick?</label>
                            {{ pickingform.as_p}}



                        </div>




                        <button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary m-3">Submit</button>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>





</html>
```

urls.py

```
path('packing/<str:pk>', views.packing, name='packing'),
```

Comment: did you try `packing/<int:pk>` ?

Comment: havent, let me try and see the outcome

Comment: @Jonas I have updated my questions